# How to find package name once Maven dependency is added

Tags: java, maven, socket.io, maven-dependency, java-package

I'm attempting to use the socket.io implementation for Java. I need 2 dependencies: 1) [Engine.IO Java Server](https://socketio.github.io/engine.io-server-java/index.html) and 2) [Socket.IO Server Java](https://github.com/trinopoty/socket.io-server-java). I'm struggling to import the actual Java packages once the dependencies have been added to my `pom.xml`. Looking at the [javadocs for Engine.IO Java Server](https://socketio.github.io/engine.io-server-java/javadocs/index.html), it looks like the package name to import should be `io.socket.engineio.server`. However, this results in an error (details below). For other dependencies that I add, what's the best way to find the package name to actually import the dependency in my Java source code?

I'm not using an IDE like IntelliJ/Eclipse. I'm just using a more simple text editor (VSCode) and a terminal. Also, I've ensured the dependencies are actually downloaded and installed in my `~/.m2/repository` directory. Here are my files/terminal output.

**Pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>game-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>game-server</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
      <artifactId>engine.io-server</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
        <artifactId>socket.io-server</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

**App.java**

```java
package com.mycompany.app;

import io.socket.engineio.server;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }

}
```

**Terminal Output**

```bash
$ mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------< com.mycompany.app:game-server >--------------------
[INFO] Building game-server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ game-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/josh/Repos/game/game-server/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ game-server ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/josh/Repos/game/game-server/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/josh/Repos/game/game-server/src/main/java/com/mycompany/app/App.java:[3,26] package io.socket.engineio does not exis
```

Comment: Before you randomly, try with import statements, you can just locate the jar in your .m2, open the jar with winzip or 7zip and find out manually.

Comment: @Prabhakaran , I unzipped the .jar. The MANIFEST.MF didn’t provide any useful information. The file path to get to the .class files was io/socket/engineio/server, which matches the package import I used.

Comment: Things like this is why IDEs exist.  Consider adding java support so VSCode